# Printing from a WinForms application

Tags: c#, printing

I am making a WinForms application and have managed to get all the interface working. I need to be able to print out a invoice at the end of a transaction. The invoice should contain a letter header with the company name address etc and other information from the forms such as invoice number, item types and prices etc.

All the item information needs to be aligned, like in a normal invoice.

Is there any way I can export the information on the forms to Word or Excel which will then fill in the information in the relevant places on the page?

Would it just be easier to print directly from the code and make sure it is aligned (etc)?

Comment: You have neglected to tell us [What have you tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com)? Where exactly are you stuck?

Comment: And the language is *pronounced* `see sharp`, but it's name is `C#`.

Comment: thats cos im using a mac keyboard and dont know the shortcut for the hash key :) and i have tried using a class named 'PCPrint' which i found, but it only allows basic printing, no alignment or anything

Answer (score 0):

I always solved printing using one the reporting engines available like Chrystal Reports, Active Reports or DevExpress to name just three. The main advantage for me is, that they provide a rather complete integration through APIs and are specialized on printing. They usually provide a rather complete designer. The complete process of printing invoices on different printers that should look good is complex.